# adding.js file in ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm working on a simple project where I included a simple js file to fetch out a data from api on click of a button. It was working when I had HTML file and js file in same folder and used by simply clicking on index.html . Now i am using expressjs for same and written all the HTML code in index.ejs file. For some reason, the js file has stopped working. I have tried changing the paths and carefully defining the path, also kept the file in same folder as of ejs file but it does not seem to work. Any suggestions would be helpful. The lines I have included in ejs file as are as follows. Here the js file is in the js folder of public folder of the project

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this problem resolved by adding the following path to jQuery src 
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"
instead of
"jquery-3.2.1.min.js"